# Add line after label inside Tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have the following code:

```
HHReviewsCell *typeCastCell = (HHReviewsCell *)tableViewCell;
HHBusinessRatings *rate = self.dataModel.reviews[indexPath.row];
typeCastCell.lblReview.text = "Review";
[typeCastCell.rating configureWithRating:rate.rating editable:NO  delegate:nil];
```

This produces a series of labels with "Review" in them. However, I want to separate each of these with a black line so that users know there are multiple reviews. Can anyone advise me on how to do this, please?

Comment: Just add a line in view after the label

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq Would I do this inside the storyboard?

Comment: Yes otherwise it will be a mess to handle programmatically :)

Comment: @AhmadIshfaq Okay, thanks! I can't seem to find a line in the drag and drop toolwindow.. All I see is `Label`, `Button` etc.. Any ideas?

Comment: There isn't a ui element of line just drag a uiview give it background color of black height 1 and width as you like and your issue is resolved :)

Comment: If it works let me know than i can answer the question and you can accept it